# Generate a random number using a mean value and exponential distribution c++

Tags: c++, random

How do I generate a random double in C++ that uses exponential distribution, and a mean with or without a standard deviation? For example, I want to make a simulation where there is a queue with processes in it. Knowing that the mean run time of the processes is 60 seconds, how can I generate random run time values for each process?

Answer (score 1):

When you mention **mean** and **standard deviation**, I think what you're looking for is normal distribution, not exponential distribution.

You may be interested to take a look at [`std::normal_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/normal_distribution).

If you look at the linked documentation, you'll find an example of how to use it:

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <iomanip>
> #include <string>
> #include <map>
> #include <random>
> #include <cmath>
> int main()
> {
>    std::random_device rd{};
>    std::mt19937 gen{rd()};
>
>    // values near the mean are the most likely
>    // standard deviation affects the dispersion of generated values from the mean
>    std::normal_distribution<> d{5,2};
>
>    std::map<int, int> hist{};
>    for(int n=0; n<10000; ++n) {
>        ++hist[std::round(d(gen))];
>    }
>    for(auto p : hist) {
>        std::cout << std::setw(2)
>                  << p.first << ' ' << std::string(p.second/200, '*') << '\n';
>    }
> }
> ```

<sup>From [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/normal_distribution)</sup>

---

Exponential distribution is not the same thing, and it takes a single parameter, the rate of events, called *lambda*.

For future readers looking for exponential distribution (since the question explicitly mention it in the title), the standard implements the exponential distribution through [`std::exponential_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/exponential_distribution).

Answer (score 0):

The C++ Standard Library provides `std::exponential_distribution`<sup>(1)</sup>, which

> Produces random non-negative floating-point values x, distributed according to probability density function:
> P(x|λ) = λe-λx

Given such a distribution<sup>(2)</sup>,

> The mean or expected value of an exponentially distributed random variable X with rate parameter λ is given by
> E[X] = 1 / λ

So that you can derive the parameter lambda from the required mean:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
  std::random_device rd;
  std::seed_seq ss{ rd(), rd(), rd() };
  std::mt19937 gen{ss};

  constexpr double mean{ 60 };
  constexpr double lambda{ 1.0 / mean }; 
  std::exponential_distribution<> d(lambda);

  for( int n=0; n<10; ++n ) {
    std::cout << d(gen) << '\n';
  }
}
```

---

1. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/exponential_distribution
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution